# Is it safe to touch 1000 Volts DC at 1 mA of constant current? 0.1 mA? 0.01 mA?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, tesla-coil, shock

I would like to study the phenomenon where thousands of volts are safe to touch. Generators like Tesla coil and static electricity generators generate discontinuous sparks, which is why they are safe to touch. If I were to build a Class-E Tesla coil capable of generating 1000 Volts at 0.01 mA of **constant** current, will it be safe to touch? will I see an arc at all?

My understanding is that in practice, it is not just current or just volts which are the deciding factor in whether or not it is safe to touch, but instead it is both of them combined: Watts. I expect 1 Watt to be safe to touch no matter if it is 1 Volt at 1 Amp, or 1000 Volts at 0.001 Amps, or 0.001 Volts at 1000 Amps.

If my understanding is wrong, please correct me.

Also, how would I then go about generating 1000 Volts DC at 0.01 mA of constant current or anything close for this study?

Comment: A 1000 volts is never safe to touch unless it is sufficiently current limited then, at the moment of touching it (and ignoring stored charge effects), it is no-longer 1000 volts but something much lower like 100 volts so, what exactly is the premise of your experiment?

Comment: know that current limiters work by dropping the voltage when the amps are too high. since the resistance of a body is not constant or stable, it's not practical to deliver the volts and amps specified except for brief periods and with proper pre-measurement.

Comment: I'll go ahead and remove your edit. It doesn't make sense to discuss random youtube videos – there's literally thousands of people on youtube that want to make you believe that there's a machine that makes power out of nowhere, or that tinfoil hats help against alien mind control satellites. You can basically find a youtube video for any unscientific claim you can imagine.And also,Mehdi's *point* is that you **need** the voltage to drive the dangerous current through your body.Not that the voltage is dangerous.He uses a constant-voltage supply at low voltages and shows that the current is low.

Comment: I would like to add, Tesla Coils are somewhat inherently safe due to the natre of high freqency current, it does not traven through your body, rather on your skin. It is called the skin effect, although it can still use sever burns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless we're talking about being cooked alive, no, it's really not the Watt that kills you. It's the current flowing through your body, making muscles contract through electrochemical reactions, and nerves disfunctional.

To achieve a dangerous current, due to the resistance of skin, your body and your contact to whatever closes the circuit with the source of electricity, you need sufficient voltage. And, of course, as you noticed, even if you have a voltage source, it must be able to source that amount of current without breaking down.

So, your wattage considerations are plain wrong. Wattage is a side effect, but the power spent in the human body has nothing to do with danger. If your 10 kV voltage source can only source 1 mA, it is *way* safer than a 100 V supply that can supply 100 mA.

Soooo, let's have a graphic:

[image: chart of lethality]

From [this](https://engineering.dartmouth.edu/safety/electrical/TheFatalCurrent.html) article.

In short: don't ever conduct more than 10 mA through a human body.

Comment: I see. So, if I had a Class-E Tesla coil capable of generating 10 kV at 1 mA of constant current, it will create arcs which I can touch for a couple of seconds?

Comment: well, that's not how electricity works. Your Tesla coil can *either* set the voltage *or* set the current. So, assume it sets the voltage and can deliver "up to" 1 mA at that voltage. Then your body *must not* have a lower resistance to the coil ground than 10 kV / 1 mA = 10 MΩ. That's not the case, your body has significantly lower resistance for this kind of loads.

Comment: @Nauro When it comes to Tesla coils the current flowing through your body is not your only concern. You also have to be aware of other issues such as regular burns (due to hot arcs) and RF burns (which can be extremely painful and cause continuous damage long after you touch the arc). Just don't touch the output of your Tesla coil. Anyone who does is an idiot.

Comment: Notice: The graphic does **not** imply that anything below 0.1A is *not* lethal!

Comment: Note that even if a DC supply can't provide more than a milliamp, it is quite capable of charging a capacitor that can source amps. And at high voltages like that, you really start to find out what is actually a capacitor. Probably my worst shock was from a plain disconnected roll of coax cable. It had previously been used to transmit 10kv or so and even though it was disconnected on both ends and rolled up for storage The cable acted as a capacitor and when I touched the end it was no good at all. I have since been paranoid about real SHV connectors even if I had to retrofit old equipment.

Answer (score 0):

So I always wondered about this. Finaly it sunk in. You would be talking open circuit 1000V. So once the maximum current available completes the circuit the voltage matches that. At 0.1mA probably about 10V.

If on the other hand 1000A is availiable and say only 12V, because of the resistance of the human body the current this time would drop to next to nothing. Now you could have wet hands and that would change things a bit. But at any current available and say only 1V then nothing would happen. Even if wet perhaps through a cut 10mA at most.

Comment: I don't buy it.  The resistance is all in the skin, and I'd need to check if a 1000V potential difference is likely to arc and break the skin, in which case, you're cooked.  "It's all fun and games until someone loses an eye"!!

Comment: If you happen to get currents in the tens of microamp range in the heart itself you can die.